# Glossaries Acronyms - Keep normal formatting in Acronyms list but use e.g. italic in the document

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

Is it possible to have an acronym shown in e.g. `\texit` inside the text but normally formatted in the list?

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[
    fontsize=11pt,
    paper=a4,
    ]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
    acronym,
    automake,
    nopostdot,
    toc,
    nomain,
    shortcuts,
    nogroupskip,
    ]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym[
    longplural={\textit{Alternating current}},
    shortplural={\textit{AC}},
    sort={AC},
    ]{AC}{\textit{AC}}{\textit{Alternating current}}
\newacronym[
    ]{BAU}{BAU}{Business as usual}

\begin{document}

\printglossary[
    type=\acronymtype,
    nonumberlist,
    style=super,
]

\bigskip

\noindent Textit: \gls{AC}\\
Normal text: \gls{BAU}.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: MWE Result]

But what I want is that `AC` and `Alternating current` should be italic in the text but not in the list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I updated the answer with a simpler code and no problems with  parenthesis. Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED** With a much simpler answer than the previous one.

[image: z]

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,
paper=a4,
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[
acronym,
automake,
nopostdot,
toc,
nomain,
shortcuts,
nogroupskip,
]{glossaries}


\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\glsi}[1]{\textit{\gls{#1}}} % <<<< added

\newacronym[
longplural={Alternating current},
shortplural={AC},
sort={AC},
]{AC}{AC}{Alternating current} 

\newacronym[sort={BAU},
]{BAU}{BAU}{Business as usual} 

\begin{document}
    
    \printglossary[
    type=\acronymtype,
    nonumberlist,
    style= super, 
    ]
    
    \bigskip
    
    \noindent Textit: \glsi{AC}\\  % using  glsi here <<<<
    Normal text: \gls{BAU}.
    
    \bigskip
    
    \noindent   \textit{AC and Alternating current} are italic in the text but not in the list.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's way better already! :) Do you have any idea how to write the parenthesis around BAU in `\textnormal` as well?